# Regarding the impact of improving the use of insecure encryption modes

Tags: android-security

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10046138

I have several questions regarding the above vulnerabilities.

1. At this time, it is possible to upload, review, and publish apps on the Google Play Console without addressing the above event. What problems may occur in the future if this vulnerability is left unaddressed?
2. I am currently releasing an app on the Google Play Store that does not support the above event. If I do not respond to any of the above issues in the future, will it have any negative impact on the apps currently published on the Google Play Store?

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10046138

We plan to implement the responses described in the above article in the future.